# How to change django date format in jquery?

Tags: jquery, django

believe me its not the duplication.
I have Django app, where I want to take date from database and append it into text using jquery.
Presently when I doing this, i am getting date like this:

```
"2015-03-25T12:00:00-06:00"
```

I want it to get displayed somehow like HH:mm mm-dd-yy. I know that Django filters can serve my purpose well but as I am outputting text using jquery, I can't use them.
In jquery, I tried something like this:

```
var date = new Date(date);
var newDate = date.toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
```

But nothing seems to workout. Any good suggestions?

Comment: You want to `dd-MM-yyyy` or `HH:mm mm-dd-yy` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by the following functions  [getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours), [getMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes), [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear)

And here is the way to do it

```
var date = new Date('2015-03-25T12:10:00');
var output = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+" "+date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getFullYear();
```

**Note:** If you want to add trailing 0 for number 0-9 then, you should do like this

```
((date.getDate() > 9) ? date.getDate() : ('0' + date.getDate()))
```

Here's the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/allaudeen/oetg7u2p/)